# Trouble working with a .TSV containing WKT

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, geocoding, well-known-text

I'm working with a .TSV file that represents district boundaries in a portion of a country in Carto. The polygon data is represented in a string column of Well-Known Text lat/long vertices, which I'm having trouble geocoding and visualizing. How would I go about representing the district boundaries as polygons on a map? Here is a screenshot of the data set for your reference. [image]

Comment: carto_db uses postgres/postgis the 'the_geom' is the geometry field that needs to be loaded for you to display your polygons.

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about doing that? I can't seem to change the 'wkt_polygon' field from a string to a geomtery, nor create a new field and transfer the WKT data to it.

Answer (score 1):

An update query statement using [ST_GeomFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) function like this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText(wkt_polygon, 4326)
```